# BizTalk deployment including a web reference

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk-deployment

Trying out BizTalk with a web service call

The request/response is working fine on my own dev machine, but not on test ...

Exported the MSI over to my deployment test server (a seperate virtual), created the application with the Application/Import and then tested it to find it not working ...

- checking the event log and it's shows an XLANG error with "Could not load file or assembly"
- checked the GAC and the BizTalk assembly isn't there ...
- so manually added it and that seemed to do the trick

Does the added web service reference mean the assembly has to be GAC'ed as part of a deployment?

And just to get me confused, tried deploying to the real test server, import the MSI, manual copy of the DLL to the GAC ... and it fails with the XLANG error in eventlog  :-(

- any idea what's going on here ?

Comment: Maybe you should post some detail. "Could not load file or assembly" - which assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What adapter are you using?  I am assuming the SOAP adapter.  If so you can look at your bindings.  Look here near figure 6:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163464.aspx

-Bryan

Comment: Ah ha ...
<br>
<i>"BizTalk will use this proxy class when sending the message. The assembly needs to be in the global assembly cache (GAC) at run time.</i>
<br>
This is a bit of a pain, means the deployment is more complicated than I'd hoped

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  I always follow this method when deploying.  Also look at automating deployment via MSBuild or the BizTalk deployment framework on Codeplex so you can do this without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Just importing the MSI will by default not include the dll.You need to run it as well (like from windows explorer or the option given after install).  This will physically move the file.  This behavior is quite useful when scaling out.  I don't think it have anything to do with the web reference specifically.